# ListView Clicked Item Highlight not working properly

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView and have a onClickListener for this ListView.
ListView is using the SimpleAdapter, and populating the Data via a map.

Whenever Item is clicked, that List Item is getting highlighted.
But the problem is, Suppose I click the 4th Item on the List and scroll the list, then every 4th element is highlighted. I'm using a Selector xml to implement the highlight functionality

I know the problem is due to the screen refresh.

But how can I avoid this problem?
Searching for the answers from about a month now. I need a solution now.

Thanks in advance.

Selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_icon_normal" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_icon_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_icon_activated" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

Below is the code for populating the listView and onclick functionality.
//Note this code is not using the selector, how with this code also, functionality is same.

```
public void populateListView() {
        //Populate the List View Here

        //Set the adapter       
        SimpleAdapter flvadapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), finalSongList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{"filename"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});

        fileListView.setAdapter(flvadapter);

        fileListView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        fileListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        fileListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        //Registering the OnItemClicklistener
        fileListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {

                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //fileListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

               updateView(position);

                index = position;
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) fileListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (hm.get("fileuri") == null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    adb.setTitle("ListView OnClick");
                    adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = " + hm.get("fileuri"));
                    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                    adb.show();
                } else {
                    //Processing the Selected File
                }
            }
        });
    }

private void updateView(int index){
        //View v=fileListView.getChildAt(index-fileListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        selectedListViewItem=fileListView.getChildAt(index);
        fileListView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        if (selectedListViewItem != null) {
            selectedListViewItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file, and any relevant code

Comment: For the ListView, I am using the generic " android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1".

Selector.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_icon_normal" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_icon_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_icon_activated" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>

Comment: what about the listView element it self?, and do you have any code related to activating/selecting an item once clicked?

Comment: @OrBar Yes, I have updated it in the question. Thanks :)
Can you please get me out of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In your `updateView()` function, you are changing the `selectedListViewItem`'s background color. up to this point everything works like you would assume however when you scroll, every so ofter another row will already be "selected" even though you didn't do it yourself.

That  is caused by view recycling, a function of `Listview` adapters that allow them to load faster by taking a row that has been scrolled out of the screen, fill it with new data and present it as is (without needing to inflate it from XML again.

Basically it will take your old blue row that is not on the screen anymore, put a new string in and display it as the new row.

The way you fix it is by implementing your own Adapter and overriding the getView method. there are a ton of resources that will show you how to do that. [Here is one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

One thing to keep in mind, once you implement your custom Adapter is that you will have to keep track of which items have been clicked so you can un-highlight and re-highlight items correctly.

Comment: Here, I'm using a SimpleAdapter and this adapter helps me to populate the ListView via a map.
While implementing the Custom Adapter I will have to implement that portion also.Can I do populate it with Custom Adapter?
Do I need to extend SimpleAdapter for this?

Comment: I've never extended `SimpleAdapter`, I've previously implemented using `ArrayAdapter` and `BaseAdapter` but either way, it's really simple and mostly boiler plate, however it can be a little intimidating the first time you dive in to do it. `BaseAdapter` is the most flexible and gives you the most control over the data, so I would use that.

Answer (score 0):

you are changing the background color of the selected item but not reset it in the adapter

try to post your adapter code

so check in adapter getView method

if item is selected
  setBackgroudColor for selected row
else
  setBackgroundColor for normal row

Comment: I'm using the SimpleAdapter. Haven't implemented my own adapter. With the selector, when Item is clicked, Color comes and goes away and then reappears when List is scrolled. Any solution, so that List item remains highlighted, once it is clicked? –

Comment: ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(position, true); try to use this for selected item

Comment: Currently, I am using it in my code.
But no luck. :(